# Google Apps Scrip onEdit()-function gives "exceeded maximum execution time"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that has been working smoothly for the last 3 weeks in Apps Script, but since a few days ago it stopped functioning. Looking at the executions there seems to be quite many running at the same time and many that also has "Timed out". Error message says "**exceeded maximum execution time**".

This is the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'B2B_LeadList' && e.range.columnStart === 22 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value === 'STARTED') {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 23).setValue(new Date());
  }

 if (sh.getName() == 'B2B_LeadList' && e.range.columnStart == 35 && e.value == 'YES') {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName('B2B_Archive');
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 36).setValue(new Date());
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }}
```

Anyone got any recommendations on how I can tweak the script? or any work around to get the script running again?
Thanks!

Tweaking the script

Comment: I don't see any reason why your code should not be working.  You should add some toast()'s to see where it's failing.  Have you check executions to see if you are getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

A single execution of Apps script can last no longer than 6 minutes and you're probably hitting this limit.
https://www.steegle.com/google-products/google-apps-script-faq

You can avoid it by splitting your script in to two.
like Script 1 is doing 1-500 rows and script 2 is doing 501-1000 rows.

Second way is to try to optimize the script

Comment: A simple trigger onEdit() function cannot last any longer than 30 seconds.